# Is there a VB .NET equivalent to C Fall Through switch?

Tags: c, vb.net, switch-statement, select-case

This is not a duplicate of this question : [VB.NET Stacking Select Case Statements together like in Switch C#/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795886/vb-net-stacking-select-case-statements-together-like-in-switch-c-java). The answer provided here does not answer my question. The answer there is stating that there is an automatic break in VB .Net, which I'm aware of. I'm asking if there's any workaround.

In C, it is possible to do something like this :

```
int i = 1;
switch (i) {
   case 1 :
     //Do first stuff
     break;
   case 2 :
     //Do second stuff
     //Fall Through
   case 3 :
     //Do third stuff 
     break;
}
```

Basically

- If `i` is 1, app will do first stuff.
- If `i` is 2, it will do second AND third stuff.
- If `i` is 3, it will do only third stuff.

Since there is an auto break at the end of each `Select case` statement in VB .Net, does anyone know how to achieve this in VB .Net ?

In a nice and pretty way I mean...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.NET Stacking Select Case Statements together like in Switch C#/Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795886/vb-net-stacking-select-case-statements-together-like-in-switch-c-java)

Comment: Not a duplicate as it doesn't answer the question...

Comment: Actually, you can't do this in c#. In order for the fall through to work, there can't be any statements between the cases. Also, the possible duplicate answers your question exactly.

Comment: C# doesn't allow "fallthrough" for the non-empty case.

Comment: C# Allows fallthrough with non empty cases!?

Comment: OK My mistake, I always thought that was possible in C#. Actually I used to do that in C...

Comment: C# actually allows "fallthrough", but not implicit one. You need to state it explicitely. It's called `goto case fooobar;`. I'm not joking. [see msdn here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/13940fs2.aspx)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AaHYaS

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yeah I just checked it you are right not possible in C#. But I know it is possible in C...

Comment: @ZoharPeled: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gT5K4h - **explicit** ones are supported. And not necessarily "down". You can jump anywhere.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, wow two wrongs make a right. It can even fall 'back up'. Can I do switch loops now?

Comment: @user6144226: [apparently yes](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p4eOGE) but that's.. a very poor idea. I also feel bad for making the dotnetfiddle into infinite loop accidentally. Fortunatelly, it defended itself against me.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Thanks! I had no idea that's possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your premise is wrong. In C# you can't fall through to the next case if the current case has statements. Trying to do so will result in a compilation error.

You can, however, (ab)use `goto case` to get this working.

```
switch(0)
{
    case 0:
        Console.WriteLine("0");
        goto case 1;
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        break;

}
```

VB.Net has [no equivalent of `goto case`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/820168/14357)

Comment: I think the OP mentioned c, not c# although the post has been updated quite a bit so maybe c# was originally mentioned?

Comment: @Igor Yes, originally it was C#.

Comment: Yeah but it's the same concept... I was wondering if there was an equivalent to that in VB .Net...

Comment: By the way - it's worth noticing that `goto case` in C# can jump to any case (upwards too) and has **no safeguards** as seen in [this infinite switch fallback loop](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p4eOGE)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl No, it really is good old `goto` from our BASIC days with a bit of sugar.

Comment: Yeah, you're stuck using `goto label` (rather that a more elegant `goto case`). But on the upside, it looks like VB can make a jump table from a `Select Case`: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fe35bbda-2a3b-4ba5-9c85-92d235b7e451/select-case-efficient-code?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: what about the infamous `GoTo` Statement??,


 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69whc95c(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: The day a goto abuse anwser is a good anwser, hell frozen over.